# Background Tint not resetting in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, colors, background

I am developing an android app in Visual Studio (Xamarin) (c#) and every time I change the background of the linear layout to lets say Gray it doesn't change to gray but to a purple colour. I believe its to do with the backgroundTint but I cant seem to remove the tint.

Any Ideas?

Thanks

[Selected Gray but showing Purple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCboQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. 
I managed to solve this my deleting android:backgroundTint="#b4b4b4ff" from the XML source code. For some reason it wouldn't delete it when I changed the background tint.